# Finding Distribution Function of Dirac Measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

"Define a probability measure $\mu$ on $(\Bbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\Bbb{R}))$ by:

$\mu = 0.3\delta_0 + 0.4\delta_1 + 0.3\delta_4$

Find the distribution function $F$ of $\mu$"

This is a question from a previous exam paper, and I am trying to get to grips with questions like these.
In my notes I have the Cumulative distribution function defined as:

$F_X(t) = \Bbb{P}({X\leq t})$

I also have the dirac measure as:

$\delta_x(A) \ = $$\left\lbrace
\matrix{1,\ x\in A\cr 0, \ x \notin A}
\right\rbrace$

I've also read something about the dirac measure being 0 at all points apart from $x=0$ where it equals 1, but it's just confusing me even more

Could anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your formula for the CDF is correct, it remains to write it as a function of the PDF:
$$
F_X(t)=\mu((-\infty,t])=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{ if }0\notin(-\infty,t], 1\notin(-\infty,t],\text{ and }4\notin(-\infty,t],\\
0.3 &\text{ if }0\in(-\infty,t], 1\notin(-\infty,t],\text{ and }4\notin(-\infty,t],\\
0.3+0.4&\text{ if }0\in(-\infty,t], 1\in(-\infty,t],\text{ and }4\notin(-\infty,t],\\
0.3+0.4+0.3&\text{ if }0\in(-\infty,t], 1\in(-\infty,t],\text{ and }4\in(-\infty,t].\\
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore,
$$
F_X(t)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ if }t<0,\\
0.3 &\text{ if }0\le t<1,\\
0.7&\text{ if }1\le t<4,\\
1&\text{ if }t\ge4.\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
Feel a bit stupid now I see how easy it is, but I get this now